# Inbuilt body parser for express is return an unexpected result

Tags: node.js, json, express, middleware, body-parser

I read an article that made me believe `app.use(express.json())` is a convenient alternative to `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))` since the will both parse the body of a request and return it as an object. However for some strange reasons in the snippet:

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/add-product',(_req, res, _next) => {
res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST" ><input type="text" name="title"><button 
type="submit">Add Product</button>');
});

app.use('/product', (req, res, _next) => {
console.log(req.body);
res.redirect('/');
});
```

The `console.log(req.body)` in the second middle-ware is returning an empty object while using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})` returns an object with the right value sent through the form. I am finding it difficult to understand, what have I done wrongly. Any good explanation will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not correct. `app.use(express.json());` is an alternative to using `app.use(bodyparser.json());`.

In fact if you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/b8e50568af9c73ef1ade434e92c60d389868361d/lib/express.js#L78), you can see that `express.json` is just an alias.

In your case, however, you need to parse the content-type *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* which is why you need to keep

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})`

as a middleware. See http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

No, `app.use(bodyParser.json())` can be replaced with `app.use(express.json())` and  getting form body, `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})` can be replaced by convinient `app.use(express.urlencoded())` when working with express version 4.16 or later